# Firebase keeps performing requests to .lp?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a Chrome Extension (using Vue), in which I use firebase. 
I added the firebase servers to my content-security-policy:

```
"script-src 'self' https://cdn.firebase.com https://*.firebaseio.com; object-src 'self'"
```

When I reload the extension in Chrome, Firebase starts querying the following domains, and keeps on doing it.

[image]

The issue is that the firebase domains are allowed in my csp, but for some reason my chrome extension is blocking these, and why do they keep looping? What is the .lp request?

Answer (score 4):

Requests to `.lp` happen when the Firebase Realtime Database client switches to using *long-polling* to communicate with the server. It does this when it's unable to communicate using its preferred WebSocket protocol.

So it looks like the Firebase client is unable to communicate with the server using WebSockets, switches to trying long-polling, and is unsuccessful with that too leading to retries.

Comment: Are there any known reasons why websockets would fail to work? I'm using Firebase in a Chrome Extension, that's where this error is happening.

Comment: Nope, I have no knowledge on why that would or wouldn't work. It's been a while since I used Firebase in Chrome extensions myself, which is why I answered your actual question on what the `.lp` calls are meant to do and why they're repeating.